# Emacs Disown Without Output in Zsh

Tags: zsh

Per [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/fkwcvx/open_emacs_through_terminal_and_continue_using/) reddit thread I hava added the following to my `.zshrc`:

`em () { emacs "$@" 2> /dev/null & disown; }`

However, when I run this command I get output like this:

```
$ em
[2] 4066
```

It's kind of annoying, and it only happens when I use the `& disown`. I've tried `emacs "$@" 2> /dev/null & disown > /dev/null;` and `emacs "$@" 2> /dev/null & disown 2> /dev/null;`, but I get similar output. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the `notify` and `monitor` options:

```
=> echo abc & disown
[1] 1205
abc
=> setopt local_options no_notify no_monitor
=> echo abc & disown                        
abc
```

more here: https://superuser.com/questions/1228411/silent-background-jobs-in-zsh